# What to ask Warren Buffet at the Berkshire Hathaway shareholder meeting?

Tags: united-states, investing

I'm 16 years old, and I'm waking up at 4am tomorrow to hopefully be one of the first people in line to get into the Berkshire Hathaway meeting. If I get the chance to ask Warren a question, what should that question be? I think the event is being streamed tomorrow so who knows, you might see your question get asked! Anyways thank you for any ideas, I hope I can talk with him. Also I understand this question is a little off topic, but please don't remove this until after tomorrow, I really don't know what I want to ask him.

Comment: If you don't know what you want to ask, why are you determined to take up his time? You can probably learn more by listening carefully to his answers to other questions; among other things, you won't be too nervous to pay attention.

Comment: "don't remove this until after tomorrow" - I respected this request, if only because I felt there was no harm waiting an extra couple days. Time to close this now.

Comment: Alright you can remove it if you want I don't really know how to... Sorry haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, when I went to the meeting a couple of years ago, the question and answer segment is mostly students asking how to pick a stock or what book they should read.  I'm sure someone else will ask but it would be interesting to hear their take on the Syrian refugee situation in Europe and how it may impact the EU in general.  Or how he/they think the drought in the south western region of the US will impact the national economy, if at all.  Like Keshlam says, if YOU don't care about the answer there's really no point to asking the question.

The most important thing you can do is listen to what he and Munger have to say.  The way they think is interesting and they have great rapport with eachother.  It's a great experience and unfortunately I wasn't able to make my schedule work to attend this year.  It's almost comical how many cans of Coke Warren will knock out through the day.

Another fun thing to do is take the shuttle to the airstrip to check out the NetJets.  I wish I had the interest and wherewithal to go when I was 16...

Comment: Thank you for the interesting questions, I didn't end up asking him any thing, sorry haha.

Comment: Pretty fun right? Did you get to see the jets?

Comment: At the convention I got to walk around inside a section of one. It was really cool, I wish I had a private jet.

Answer (score -1):

I would be curious how he balanced having [two female life partners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Buffett#Personal_life) at once. Not sure I would ask that at the shareholder meeting though ;)

Comment: Haha! Yeah that'd be scarry to ask in front of all these people

Comment: That question should be taken elsewhere. Some folks can make poly relationships work. Unfortunately that's fewer than the number of folks who claim to be trying to do so.